# Mockito - mocking RestOperations

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have:

```
Map<String, String> vars = new HashMap<String, String>();
String r = restOperations.getForObject(url, String.class, vars);
```

In my test I try to mock RestOperations:

```
@Mock
RestOperations restOperations;

when(restOperations.getForObject(Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.eq(String.class), Matchers.notNull())).thenReturn("ok");
```

This never get triggered.

Does anyboy see why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the problem is with method overloading. `getForObject` has two overloaded versions taking three arguments:

```
<T> T getForObject(String url, Class<T> responseType, Map<String, ?> uriVariables);

<T> T getForObject(String url, Class<T> responseType, Object... uriVariables);
```

You are actually mocking the second one while you want to mock the first one. To help the static method resolution cast the `notNull()` matches explicitly:

```
when(restOperations.getForObject(
  Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.eq(String.class), (Map)Matchers.notNull())
).thenReturn("ok");
```

Or even better, use `anyMap()`:

```
 when(restOperations.getForObject(
   Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.eq(String.class), Matchers.anyMap())
 ).thenReturn("ok");
```

Comment: Even better: `when(restOperations.getForObject(
   Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.eq(String.class), Matchers.anyMapOf(String.class, String.class))
 ).thenReturn("ok");` Thanks alot!

Comment: Note that mamruoc's snippet only works in Mockito 1.9.0 and higher.

Answer (score 1):

**Thanks for your Answer, It was really helpful.**

**Following is the complete source code, thought that it would be helpful for others.**

```
public class HandlerTest {

    private Handler handler;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        handler = new HandlerImpl();
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethodtoTest() {
        String param1 = "123456";
        String param2 = "3736272";
        String param3 = "838912";

        RestTemplate mock = Mockito.mock(RestTemplate.class);
        Mockito.when(mock.getForObject( Matchers.anyString(), Matchers.eq(String.class), Matchers.anyMapOf(String.class, String.class)) ).thenReturn("ok");
        handler.setRestTemplate(mock);

        String actualResponse = handler.MethodtoTest(param1, param2, param3);

        Assert.assertNotNull(actualResponse);
        Assert.assertEquals("ok",actualResponse);
}
```